# MySQLDump - Is there any way I can enter the password with -p or --password?

Tags: mysql

I have an Ubuntu server with MySQL.

On the command line, this works

```
  mysqldump -u root -p paydaydebt
```

(then I have to manually type the password)

On the command line, these do not work:

```
mysqldump -u root -p{password} paydaydebt 
mysqldump -u root --password={password} paydaydebt
```

Is there any way I can enter the password with -p or --password?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should **not**. Given the password at the command line is evil as it is visible to everybody issuing a `ps` or `top`.

The recommended way is to specify the password in a separate file and then add a command line switch `--defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/mysqlpassword.cnf`

The `mysqlpassword.cnf` then contains (only):

```
[mysqldump]
# The following password will be sent to mysqldump 
password="ThisIsThePassword"
```

Make sure that this file is only readable for the user executing `mysqldump` (preferable `root`).

Answer (score 6):

Don't leave a space between the -p and the password that you are passing to mysqldump. If you do put a space in the password will be interpreted as the name of a database to act upon.

```
mysqldump -uroot -pPassword dbase
```

would dump database dbase

```
mysqldump -uroot -p Password dbase
```

would ask for a password and try to dump the database Password.

However as mailq says you should probably avoid the use of the password on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer!  The topic that is flagged as the answer isn't actually answering the question at all but rather providing an opinion on implementation.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [mailqs](https://serverfault.com/a/303541/192924) answer: --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/mysqlpassword.cnf must be the first option in the command. Example:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/mysqlpassword.cnf -u root paydaydebt
```

Comment: This answer solves the error "mysqldump: unknown variable 'defaults-extra-file=..."

Answer (score 1):

If your password including special characters, you must escape with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

What's your mysql version?
Normally, the following syntax should work just fine:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p'ThisIsThePassword' mysql
```

Include the password in between ' 's to avoid special chars being parsed by the shell or otherwise escape them. If that doesn't work try using "" instead.